# Is there way to change anchor behaivor?

Tags: javascript, php

I have problem. Anchor link changes url. After i press a tag with #down. My url changes to localhost/#down . My anchor link change url. is there way to pervent anchor to change url?
Thanks

Comment: Specify you question, pls. What result you need?

Comment: Provide some more information

Answer (score 0):

Use the following javascript code to prevent the default behaviour of your anchor

```
document.getElementById("myAnchor").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
});
```

Comment: The idenfier "myAnchor" is replaced by the id of the anchor